# React URL Param routes failing on Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I'm having issues with react url param routes and it's giving out error on amplify.

**Example routes with url params**

```
<AsyncSearchResultsList path="search/:q" />
<AsyncSearchDetailedInfo path="search/user/:id" />
```

**This is the error I'm getting**
[image]

**On amplify I have these redirects setup**
[image]

I can't navigate to either of these routes and it works fine for other routes without parameters
All of these routes are also working perfectly on localhost

Is there something I'm missing? I'm using Reach Router in my react project.

**Update:**

Figured what seemed to be part of it, the issue I was having was resolved. Amplify wasn't handling the Lazy loaded route components properly, data is flowing and the page is loading now after refactoring. But another issue came up, the page now displays blank whenever I navigate to those routes directly. I'm pretty sure it's an issue with Amplify's redirect rules. Still need help!

Comment: Can you explain how you solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

To those who need to use react and params

| Source address | Target address | Type | Country code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| </^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|map|json|webp)$)([^.]+$)/> | /index.html | 200 (Rewrite) | - |
| /search?customer=<customerid> | /search?customer=<customerid> | 301 (Redirect - Permanent) | - |

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa
and
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#query-parameters